# MySQL: How do I do ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE where two primary keys MUST match?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to be able to run all of the following within one query call using mysqli->multi_query, which is why this is tricky. I have a table that consists of the following columns:

- id
- email
- event_promo_code
- event_id

When the script is run, I need to be able to insert new rows or UPDATE a row if both the `id` AND `event_id` match an existing record (not just one key or the other).

What I have now is:

```
INSERT INTO `rsvps` 
SET id='$rsvpID', email='$rsvpEmail', 
      event_promo_code='$rsvpEventCode', event_id='$eventID' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='$rsvpID', 
      email='$rsvpEmail', event_promo_code='$rsvpEventCode', event_id='$eventID';
```

`id` is my primary key. If I also set `event_id` as a key, it does an update when either id matches a record or event matches a record, but doesn't check to see if BOTH match at the same time before it updates.

Comment: So what happens if only one key matches?  You want the insert to fail with no update?

Comment: How is `id` generated? Is `event_id` a foreign key column?

Comment: The idea is that the same id can be used multiple times as long as event_id's are different. So if event_id matches but id doesn't match, it would just do a regular insert. If id matches, but event_id doesn't match, it would also do a regular insert.

Comment: @user1418227: In that case, the only `UNIQUE KEY` on your table should be `(id, event_id)`.

Comment: The admin will upload a CSV file with all of these columns pre filled out. id isn't auto_increment since it is defined by a third party who will create these CSV files

Comment: So I guess your table has a compound primary key, (id-event_id)?

Comment: I guess so, but how do I make that happen? Not a MySQL pro unfortunately. I'm using Sequel Pro mac client to do my structure/setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

The only `UNIQUE` constraint on your table should be defined over the combined columns `(id, event_id)`.  It sounds as though this should probably also be your primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE rsvps DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, eventid);
```

(Obviously you will also need to `DROP` any other `UNIQUE` keys which have been defined).

Comment: Awesome thanks! This worked and totally makes sense. It wasn't letting me do this (id, eventid) until I dropped the other key which is why I was having trouble before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) command. For your case, create unique index from `id` and `event_id`:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

Comment: Would that replace only if both id and event_id match the record at the same time? Because that's what I'm looking for. Not just replace if one of the two matches

Comment: Sort of. Replacement will take place if: `id` matches (primary key) or if `id` and `event_id` (unique index) matches but not if only `event_id` matches. If `id` + `event_id` match is the only desired case, consider creating creating composite primary key from `id` and `event_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO rsvps (id, email, event_promo_code, event_id)
 values('$rsvpID', '$rsvpEmail', '$rsvpEventCode', '$eventID')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE id='$rsvpID', email='$rsvpEmail', event_promo_code='$rsvpEventCode', event_id='$eventID';
```